# Implementing CoroutineScope in ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, coroutinescope

Why and when do we actually need to implement `CoroutineScope` in a `ViewModel`. Inside ViewModel you can use `viewModelScope` when you want to tied your Coroutine to the ViewModel thus when `onCleared` gets called all running coroutines will be cancelled automatically. When you implement `CoroutineScope` you can directly call `launch`, what scope does it use? I am guessing it uses the one provided at `override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext`. Does implementing `CoroutineScope` in a ViewModel means you want to handle the cancellation of coroutine by yourself?

Comment: I just realized maybe the reason you're asking this question is that you've seen examples of people making their ViewModel or Activity class implement CoroutineScope. I think these examples are probably outdated and come from before the Android Jetpack framework had a `viewModelScope` at all. It should be very rare that you would ever want to do anything besides using `viewModelScope`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes I am reading some examples and you are probably right, I might be looking on a outdated approach. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not very commonly necessary. The purpose of creating a CoroutineScope is to manage the lifecycle of multiple coroutines. If for some reason you have some coroutines you want to launch in a ViewModel, and you want to possibly cancel all of them at some time other than when the ViewModel is destroyed, then it would be handy to have a separate CoroutineScope from `viewModelScope` to launch those coroutines from. It would be up to you to cancel this scope at the appropriate time to avoid coroutines living longer than you want them to and leaking memory.

If your ViewModel itself implements CoroutineScope and you directly call `launch`, it is using itself as the scope that launches the coroutine. But it's still up to you to cancel it at the appropriate time. Otherwise, the ViewModel could be in destroyed state, but still have some coroutines running in its scope and hanging onto memory and preventing the ViewModel from being freed to the GC.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple coroutines? Can you include some sample codes for different use case? That would be really helpful as well. Thanks

Comment: You might be fetching something from a database with one coroutine, making a request to a web address on another coroutine, and mapping some Flow to a StateFlow using `stateIn` in another coroutine. Typically, you would want to cancel all of these when your ViewModel is destroyed, so you would launch them on `viewModelScope` so that can happen automatically. The use case for creating a separate CoroutineScope from `viewModelScope` is so narrow that it's hard to come up with a good example.

Comment: Maybe as part of your UI there's a way to change users and you want to cancel all currently running coroutines that are based on that user ID. You could do this by creating a separate scope that you start all coroutines from that use the user ID. When the user ID changes, you cancel that scope and replace it with a new one to easily cancel all related coroutines without cancelling ones that are not related to user ID.

Comment: So am I correct that you will only probably do this when you want to handle the cancellation of coroutines by yourself?

Comment: Yes, and usually you don't need to.

Comment: How many scope do we have? Currently this are the well known scope I am aware of GlobalScope, MainScope, viewModelScope, lifeCycleScope.

Comment: MainScope isn’t one—that’s a factory function to create a scope. So on Android there are just those three provided for you.

Answer (score 0):

We can launch multiple coroutine within viewmodelscope.launch{} without coroutineScope.But Sometimes we may need values from all running coroutine to create new result.if it returns a value we can use async{}.await() but if it returns a job we can't expect updated result .

So if we launch our all coroutines within our child coroutine using coroutineScope{} ,parent coroutine will wait for child coroutine to finish it's executions before return the result.

```
viemodelScope.launch{val count= getCountValue()  }//parent coroutine

 suspend fun getCountValue(): Int {
        var count = 0
        lateinit var asyncDeferredResult: Deferred<Int>
 //child coroutine
        coroutineScope { 
            //returns job
            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                delay(1000)
                count = 10
            }
            //launching another coroutine using async coroutine builder within child coroutine
            asyncDeferredResult = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
                delay(3000)
                return@async 50 
            }

        }  //child coroutine scope end


        //here the parent coroutine  guaranties ,the completion of all task within child coroutine scope  before return the value .
        //  we will get expected result (10+50=60) 
        //if you launch more than one coroutine without child coroutinescope,sometimes you will get 0+50=50 at the end

        return count + asyncDeferredResult.await()}
```

Comment: There's no reason to ever create a CoroutineScope using the CoroutineScope "constructor" if you're not going to store it in a property so you can use it to manage its lifecycle. This is a well-known Kotlin coroutines anti-pattern. If you truly have a coroutine that you want to never cancel, you can use GlobalScope. Even this should be rare, because usually you should care about how long coroutines are allowed to run for.